# Simplifying $\sin(4x)\cos(4x)$

Tags: trigonometry

> Simplify $\sin(4x)\cos(4x)$ using double angle or compound trigonometry.

Can someone please show me how its done, Ive tried several times but no where near the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "solve"? What is there to solve?

Comment: As stated there is nothing to solve here.  Do you mean $\sin(4x) \cos(4x) = 0$?

Comment: Simplify, sorry.

Comment: @RedQueen10101   is it what i have answered or you mean different one?

Comment: @dato yes you got the answer although could you elaborate further on how you got sin8x/2?

Comment: represent  $8*x=2*(4*x)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [double angle formula](http://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/mc-ty-doubleangle-2009-1.pdf) is $ \  2 \sin\theta\cos\theta = \sin(2\theta) \iff \sin\theta\cos\theta = \frac{1}{2} \sin(2\theta)$.

By applying this formula with $\theta = 4x$, we obtain

$$\sin4x\cos4x=\frac{1}{2} \sin(8x).$$

Answer (score 10):

$\sin4x\cos4x$   using identiity that  $\sin(2\theta)=2\sin\theta\cos\theta$,we get

$\sin4x\cos4x=\frac{\sin(8x)}{2}$

Comment: I'm reasonably sure the question is asking to simplify in terms of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$.

Comment: Also, named math operators should appear upright, and the common ones have their own code for this purpose (e.g. `\sin`, `\log` - [see entry 11 in our MathJax guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264)).

Comment: ok i  was thinking that he wanted  like this,then it is  his  rights  to ask it more clearly,what does mean simplify in terms of sin and cosine?by which way?i did not understand

Comment: In textbooks, sometimes “simplify” means “complicate”. I like this answer fine.

Comment: I feel like Dato has the right of it.  This is set up as a clear application of the double angle formula as you would find it in the exercises of a textbook.